# Ankh SVN: Copying code to a new branch without checking into the current branch

Tags: svn, merge, ankhsvn

All of our dev is done via a branch, where a branch relates to a version to be released.  Sometimes, we start working in the latest branch but for some reason a new minor branch is opened.  Now, I find myself in this position.  Because of what I was working on I did not check it into the original branch and I don't know how to move my code to the new branch.  Make sense?

Asked another way:

- Checkout v1.16.0
- Do local work (no check-in)
- v1.16.0 goes into code freeze
- Checkout v1.16.1
- ?????? - how do I move the local changes in v1.16.0 to v1.16.1?

I am planning on using BeyondCompare as I know the files I need to move content on.  Hoping there is a SVN (Ankh SVN) way of doing this instead.  This is **NOT** a merge as v1.16.0 never got checked in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute

svn switch v1.16.1

This changes your branch but preserve your local changes.

Comment: Do you know if this is available in Ankh?  If it is, I've not found it yet.  I'll look at Tortoise in a few but I usually don't open Explorer all that often.

Comment: Never mind - I found it under the Ankh/Subversion/Swith Versions option.  Will certainly give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching I think [this blog entry](http://jason.famularo.org/post/14391495296/simulating-tfs-shelvesets-in-subversion) covers it best.  While this blog is trying to address Shelve Sets in SVN the practice of creating a patch file is still viable.  I am using Ankh SVN in my Visual Studio.  The blog entry shows how to do it from Tortoise SVN.  And this is the notes of what I've discovered so far:

1. In both Ankh and Subversion you can create a patch (basically a diff that is saved locally)
2. Only in Tortoise can you Apply Patch into your local code.  I have not yet found a way in Ankh to do this.